# No mapping metadata found for java.util.Date

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I'm using spring-boot + spring-data-rest + spring-data-mongodb and I have a class which is exposed via a Repository and I've recently upgraded from 1.3.7 to 1.4.3 Release of Spring Boot.

The problem is if I leave the field createdDate available... I get the following error when checking the API

Last year I had a similar project and it worked fine with Spring Boot 1.3.2, didn't have to implement some custom solution or configure something else.

**Later edit** just downgraded to 1.3.2 ... same error ...

***"No mapping metadata found for java.util.Date"***

```
public class SomeMessage {

@Id
private String id; 

private Map<String,String> messageDetails;

private String replyToId;

private String contactFormId;

//@CreatedDate
private Date createdDate;

//...getters, setters, what not

}
```

Later edit 2 ... full stack trace

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No mapping metadata found for java.util.Date
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:229) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1197) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:79) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1145) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:871) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:284) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:272) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:322) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:272) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:232) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:192) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:188) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:79) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:2295) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1949) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1767) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1750) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:624) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:357) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:219) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
```

Comment: Can you add all the relevant code to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much code to share since everything is autoconfigured by spring boot :)

Comment: How is your mongo/boot configuration set up ? Looks like Spring is not able to find `SomeMessage` class. Make sure your `SomeMessage` is in the same package as your boot class.

Comment: it is in the same package , otherwise I'd need to add some annotations to inform spring about it ... I'm still trying some other workarounds but they don't seem to work ... and the strange part is that some projects worked fine last year

Comment: You still have `@Document` annotation though right ? See if that is there.

Comment: that's odd, I've just tested this before reading your comment and that was the issue, post the answer and i'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `@Document` annotation for the POJO class.

From the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.10.0.M1/reference/html/),

> @Document - applied at the class level to indicate this class is a
>   candidate for mapping to the database. You can specify the name of the
>   collection where the database will be stored.

**Update:** Although it should work without @Document as it is not mandatory annotation.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem with a message:

> No mapping metadata found for class org.bson.types.ObjectId

My entity had `@Document` annotation.
There was a field `Set<ObjectId>` in that entity annotated with `@DBRef(lazy = true)`.
Removing `@DBRef` annotation solved my problem.